# Shutdown from panel does not work

Tags: release-hera, wingpanel, shutdown

If I leave the computed idle for a long amount of time when I try to shutdown using the options from the top bar nothing happens. As a work-around, I can log out first and then use the shutdown in the greeter top right-hand corner. Otherwise, shutdown from the terminal also works.

Grub options are as follows:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi=force reboot=acpi"

In /var/log/syslog I see this error:

wingpanel[4143]: EndSessionDialog.vala:112: Unable to reboot: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InteractiveAuthorizationRequired: Interactive authentication required.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of normal updates, this problem appears to be solved.